# Scala copy method returning a different type parameter?

Tags: scala

How is it possible in the following example to get a different type parameter when copying a parameterised type:

```
sealed trait PreTax
sealed trait PostTax
case class Pay[State](s:String)
val pay = Pay[PreTax]("preTax")
val payPost:Pay[PostTax] = pay.copy(s="taxed")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `pay.copy[PostTax](s="taxed")`.

I think there are better ways to model this. At least you should limit the `State` type parameter to `PreTax` and `PostTax` :

```
sealed trait Tax
sealed trait PreTax extends Tax
sealed trait PostTax extends Tax
case class Pay[State <: Tax](s:String)
```

This way you can only create a `Pay[PreTax]` or a `Pay[PostTax]`.

Even better might be :

```
sealed trait Pay { def s: String }
case class PayPreTax(s: String) extends Pay {
  def payTax(): PayPostTax = PayPostTax(this.s)
}
case class PayPostTax(s: String) extends Pay

object Pay {
  def apply(s: String): Pay = PayPreTax(s)
}
```

Which you could use as :

```
scala> val pay = Pay("foobar")
pay: Pay = PayPreTax(foobar)

scala> pay match {
     |   case pre: PayPreTax => pre.payTax  // pay tax if not paid
     |   case post => post                  // tax is already paid
     | }
res8: Pay = PayPostTax(foobar)
```